# Do small 1:1 isolation transformers exist?

Tags: transformer, isolation, nixie

I am building a Nixie clock that will be powered from 110V wall power. The design is based around having this 110Vac as the input voltage, but I wanted to put an isolation transformer inline for safety.

This thing will *maybe* go up to 10W, so I don't need a huge high power transformer. But I cannot find a 1:1 small transformer. Are these not a thing? Am I looking in the wrong place? Or do I need to redesign my circuit to use a different input voltage?

Comment: I get 32 hits on Digikey for power transformers with between 10 and 20 VA rating, 100-130 V primary rating, and 100-130 V secondary rating. Some of them have two secondaries that can be connected series or parallel to get 240 or 120 V secondary. And typical size seems to be about 50 x 50 mm.

Comment: this may help you get started in your search ... https://cpc.farnell.com/block/tim60/transformer-isolating-60va/dp/TF01496

Comment: These were definitely helpful. Sometimes I am not very good at identifying the parameters I should be choosing on places like DigiKey, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're scavenging parts, you could consider using two similar transformers such as 120:12 and then 12:120.

Or follow the suggestion of The Photon and search for a new in-stock part- there's a 12VA "Signal" (the manufacturer) part for about USD 11. in one-off. It has a nice split-bobbin construction.

Comment: I see the exact one you are talking about, and that very well be the one I go with.